# Dynamic forms with django and google app engine?

Tags: python, django, forms, google-app-engine, dynamic-forms

My senior project group and I are designing a form for django in google app engine (python) and we were wondering if there is a way to make a dynamic form.  That is, that the user can click on a button to add fields to a form, like we have a section where  the user enters data about special tests, but depending on the situation, they could be 0 to quite a few tests.  If the user is not going to use the tests, or only use few, we don't want to waste lots of space with tons of fields that are going to be blank.  We have seen examples of this done with javascript and html forms, but not for django and we are having trouble figuring out how to do it.  Any advice on how to do this, or if it is even possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you against using JavaScript in addition to Django?

Comment: WE are fine using javascript, but we just haven't found a good way to do it javascript, but we are happy to use it if it will work

Comment: Does a single test fit in a single HTML input?

Comment: a test will actually need to be about three text input boxes, so each click of the button will generate three new inputboxes

Comment: A library like jQuery will let you easily add the inputs to the page and is well documented elsewhere (I use their template library for this). I was going to suggest that you can name all of the generated fields with the same name so that your server code gets them as a list of values and then in the clean() method of your form you can gather them up and do something with them. I doubt you get the fields in any guaranteed order though so you could not use the order to match fields that belong together. You could append a number to the end of the field name and still use clean() to gather them.

Comment: Another option would be:

 - have a hidden 'tests' field in your form
 - on the client side catch the submit event (of the form)
 - package up the data from your test fields into an easy to transmit and parse form (JSON works)
 - place that data in the hidden field
 - on the server side (in the clean method for the hidden field) parse the test data into a useful structure

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers guys, but our group decided to go with a different design to avoid this problem completely since we all do not know much javascript or anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Formsets might be of use...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Ok so that sounds promising, but maybe i just read it wrong, but how can I do it on the fly from the user input or is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're not going to use any JavaScript for that then the user experience is not going to be the best, but yes, there are ways to do that.

Since by definition Django is generating the templates server side you need to know up front how many extra fields you're going to show to the end user.

Just a simple example of how to display 4 extra fields using Django:

```
{% for i in 4|get_range %}
  Extra field: <input name="extra_{{i}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Even if you're using [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) there are ways to change templates and add your own fields.

Comment: I'm happy to use javascript, my group just doesn't know a ton of it and we have yet to find a good example on how to do it.